# return sum all numbers in a range

Tags: javascript, sorting, reduce

```
function sumAll(arr) {
    var list = [];

    for (var i = arr[0]; i <= arr[1]; i++) {
        list.push(i);
    }

    var total = list.reduce(function(a, b) {
        return a + b;

    });

    return total;
}

sumAll([10, 5]);
//sumAll([1, 4]);  //returns 10
//sumAll([5, 10]); //returns 45
//sumAll([4, 1]);
```

I need to sum every number in between the given arguments. For `sumAll([1, 4])` and `sumAll([5, 10])`. The code will pass because it creates all numbers in between the two arguments and adding it. However, for `sumAll([10, 5])` and `sumAll([4, 1])`, because the greater number is first argument, I believe it does not run var list. I tried using `.sort()` method in between so that the numbers are sorted but can't get it to work. How can I use `Math.min()` and `Math.max()` for this code to work?

Comment: Don't forget to pass `0` for the accumulator to `reduce`!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Easiest way is to use the mathematical formula

```
1+2+...+n = n(n+1)/2
```

Here you want the sum,

```
m+(m+1)+...+n
```

where `m=arr[0]` and `n=arr[1]`.  This is equal to the difference

```
(1+2+...+n) - (1+2+...+(m-1))
```

which substituting the above formula twice is equal to

```
n(n+1)/2 - (m-1)m/2
```

So the correct code is

```
function sumAll(arr) {
  var min = arr[0];
  var max = arr[1];
  return (max*(max+1) - (min-1)*min)) / 2;
}
```

---

Original answer (do not use - left for posterity):

Here's how I'd use `Math.min` and `Math.max` to do this:

```
function sumAll(arr) {
    var list = [];

    var lower = Math.min(arr[0], arr[1]);
    var upper = Math.max(arr[0], arr[1]);

    for (var i = lower; i <= upper; i++) {
        list.push(i);
    }

    var total = list.reduce(function(a, b) {
        return a + b;
    });

    return total;
}
```

Someone else posted code using `arr[0] < arr[0] ? arr[0] : arr[1]`; IMO the `Math.min` and `Math.max` functions make for more readable code than the ? : operator.

Also, two more cents: I believe it would be simpler to not make a `var list` at all; instead say `var total = 0` and increment it.  Like this:

```
function sumAll(arr) {
    var lower = Math.min(arr[0], arr[1]);
    var upper = Math.max(arr[0], arr[1]);

    var total = 0;

    for (var i = lower; i <= upper; i++) {
        total += i;
    }

    return total;
}
```

Comment: The accepted answer should be the one suggested by @Nigel. It uses a formular for your problem instead of a loop or list!

Comment: Thanks @PatrickDorn.  Updated my answer as well.  I don't know why I didn't think of that formula when I was originally posted.

Answer (score 7):

This is one of those times where mathematical equations come in handy. Check out this code:

```js
function sumAll(arr) {
  max = Math.max(arr[0], arr[1]);
  min = Math.min(arr[0], arr[1]);
  return (max * (max + 1) / 2) - ((min - 1) * min / 2);
}
```

Quite simple logic, right? :)

Comment: Not simple if you do not share the formula behind that trully.

Comment: Best answer so far. Use mathematics, not brute force ;)  Explanation:
http://mathcentral.uregina.ca/qq/database/qq.02.06/jo1.html

Answer (score 1):

```js
function sumAll(arr) {

    var first = arr[0] > arr[1] ? arr[1] : arr[0],
        last = arr[0] > arr[1] ? arr[0] : arr[1];
        sum = 0;
    for (var i = first; i <= last; i++) {
        sum += i;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function sumAll(arr) {
  var max = Math.max.apply(null, arr);
  var min = Math.min.apply(null, arr);
  var arr2 = [];

  for (var i = min; i <= max; i++) {
    arr2.push(i);
  }

  return arr2.reduce(function(sum, item) {
    sum += item;
    return sum;
  }, 0);
}

console.log( sumAll([1, 4]) )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function sumAll(arr) {
   let min = Math.min(...arr)
   let max = Math.max(...arr)
   let sum = 0
    for (let i = min; i <= max; i++){
    sum += i
  }
  return sum;
}

sumAll([1, 4]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the while loop:

```
function sumAll(arr) {
    var i = Math.min(...arr)
    var total = 0
    while(i <= Math.max(...arr)) {
        total += i
        i++
    }

    return total;
}
sumAll([1, 4];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the array to the `Math.min` and `Math.max` functions.

```js
function sumAll(arr) {
  var list = [];

  for (var i = Math.min.apply(null, arr); i <= Math.max.apply(null, arr); i++) {
    list.push(i);
  }

  var total = list.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
  }, 0);

  return total;
}

[[10, 5], [1, 4], [5, 10], [4, 1]].forEach(function(range) {
  console.log(range.join(' -> ') + ' = ' + sumAll(range));
});
```

Output:

```
10 -> 5 = 45
1 -> 4 = 10
5 -> 10 = 45
4 -> 1 = 10
```

Answer (score 0):

`.sort()` sort the array by string, use **compareFunction** to sort by number value:

```
arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a - b;
});
```

if you want to use min or max you pass the array as arguments:

1) `Math.max.apply(this, arr);` || `Math.min.apply(this, arr);`

2) `Math.max(arr[0], arr[1])` || `Math.min(arr[0], arr[1])`

Answer (score 0):

**Javascript code:**

```
function myFunction(arr) {
  console.log(arr);
  var list = [];

  var startVal = arr[0];
  console.log(startVal);
  var stopVal = arr[1];
  console.log(stopVal);

  while(startVal < stopVal+1){
    list.push(startVal++);
  }
      console.log(list);

      var total = list.reduce(function(a, b) {
          return a + b;

      });

     // return total;
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = total;
  }
```

**HTML CODE:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <button onclick="myFunction([5,10])">Try it</button>
  <div id="demo"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way of doing it:

```
function sumAll(arr) {
  var sortedArray = arr.sort(function(a,b) { 
    return a-b;
  });

  return sortedArray.reduce(function(a, b, start, arr) {
    var temp = a, subTotal = a;
    while (temp < b - 1) {
      subTotal += ++temp;
    }

    return subTotal + b;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is how I roll

```
function sumAll(arr) {
return (arr[0]+arr[1])*(Math.max(...arr)-Math.min(...arr)+1)/2;;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer simplicity....

```
function sumAll(arr) {
 var max = Math.max.apply(null, arr);
 var min = Math.min.apply(null, arr);
 var sum = 0;
 for(var i = min; i <= max; i++)
 sum = sum + i;
 return sum;
}
sumAll([1, 4]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function sumAll(arr) {
  const rangeStart = Math.min(arr[0], arr[1]);
  const rangeEnd = Math.max(arr[0], arr[1]);
  const numberOfDigits = rangeEnd - rangeStart + 1;

  return (rangeEnd + rangeStart) * numberOfDigits / 2;
}
```

It is kind of:
https://betterexplained.com/articles/techniques-for-adding-the-numbers-1-to-100/

But not starting always at 1 but at "rangeStart" and the numberOfDigits is not always rangeEnd, but the idea is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Between α and β, there are β−α+1 numbers. We need

```
S=α+(α+1)+⋯+β=β+(β−1)+⋯+α
```

Adding vertically, we have

```
2S=(β−α+1)(α+β)
```

Hence

```
S=(β−α+1)(α+β)2
```

This "reverse and add" technique is due to Gauss and can be used to sum any arithmetic progression as well.

```
function sumAll(arr) {
  let alpha = Math.min(...arr);
  let beta= Math.max(...arr); 
  return ((beta - alpha + 1)*(alpha + beta))/2;      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this one? following the Gauss Formula:

```js
function sumAll(arr) {
    return arr.reduce((a,b) => (a+b)*(Math.abs(a-b) + 1) / 2)
}

console.log(sumAll([1,4])); //10
console.log(sumAll([5,10])); //45
console.log(sumAll([10,5])); //45
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this O(1) approach is probably the best way to go:

```
function SumRange(a, b) {
    if (a > b) {
        return 0;
    }

    const sum = (b * ++b) / 2;
    return a > 1 ? sum - SumRange(0, --a) : sum;
}

var array = [1, 100];

console.log(SumRange(array[0], array[1]));//5050
console.log(SumRange(10, 100));//5005
```

The idea is to silo off the SumRange equation so that it can be the single source of truth that can be called from anywhere. Reusability is always a plus.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function sumAll(arr) {
  let sum = 0
  let temp

  if (arr[0] > arr[1]) {
    temp = arr[0]

    arr[0] = arr[1]

    arr[1] = temp
  }

  for (let i = arr[0]; i <= arr[1]; i++) {
    sum += i
  }

  return sum;
}

console.log(sumAll([4, 1]))
```

Comment: Please don't post answers that aren't substantially novel to already-answered questions. If you do post a new answer to an older question, please add an explanation of why your solution is different/better than the already posted answers.

Answer (score -2):

I would go simple:

```
function sumAll(arr) {

  var sum = 0;

  arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b;
  });

  for (var i = arr[0]; i <= arr[arr.length - 1]; i++) {
   sum += i;
  }

  return sum;

}

sumAll([4, 1]);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!